# How do I use a imported dataset with "RStudio -> Import Dataset -> From Text (base)"

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio I have pressed

> File -> Import Dataset -> From text (base)

I selected my dataset "dataset_height_male_female.csv" and I got it working:

[image]

Now I created a new R Markdown file and I want to use the dataset that I have imported.

[image]

However I get this error:

> Error in summary(dataset_height_male_female) : object 'dataset_height_male_female' not found

Answer (score 1):

When you knit the object `dataset_height_male_female` it is executed in a new environment.
But your object `dataset_height_male_female` is in your environment at the moment, but not in the new one knit creates.

You have to add the object in the new environment. e.g. put the import sequence (code is on the right lower part when you do it with import dataset) to the first chunk in rmarkdown

for example:

```
test <- read_csv("test.csv")
summary(test)
```